# Работа Observable из RxJs в Angular 2/5

Tags: angular2, angular5, rxjs

Не могу понять работу `Observable` в *Angular 2/5*. Пишу своё 2-е приложение на Angular. В нём 2 сервиса.

Один, `./friends.service.ts`, берёт из JSON-файла массив объектов типа `Friend`.

Второй, `./shared-friends.service.ts`, должен раздавать всем компонентам этот список друзей + делать некоторую его обработку, в частности, добавлять каждому объекту `Friend` новое свойство - оценку пользователем (количество звёзд от 1-й до 5).

Не пойму, как работать с возвращаемыми объектами `Observable<Friend[]>`. Нормальный массив содержится лишь в одной части программы, в остальных он пуст. Ниже листинги. В комментариях после `console.log` содержится результат.

Сервис **`./friends.service.ts`** (читает из JSON-файла массив объектов `Friend`):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from './friend';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable()
export class FriendsService {

    public apiHost: string = './assets/generated.json';

    constructor(private http: Http, private messageService: MessageService) {
        this.getFriends().subscribe();
    }

    getFriends(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get(this.apiHost);

    }

}
```

Сервис **`./shared-friends.service.ts`** (Раздаёт массив объектов `Friend` и вносит некоторые изменения в объекты):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Friend } from './friend';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { FriendsService } from './friends.service';

@Injectable()
export class SharedFriendsService {

    constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService) { }

    private friends: Observable<Friend[]>;

    getFriends():Observable<Friend[]> {
        this.friendsService.getFriends().subscribe(result => {
            this.friends = result.json();
            console.log(this.friends); // Массив объектов, как и надо: (23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
        });
        console.log(this.friends); // undefined
        return this.friends;
    }

}
```

Компонент **`./friends-list/friends-list.component.ts`** (используя сервисы выводит список друзей):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from '../friend';
import { FriendsService } from '../friends.service';
import { SharedFriendsService } from '../shared-friends.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-friends-list',
  templateUrl: './friends-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./friends-list.component.css']
})

export class FriendsListComponent implements OnInit {

    public friends: Observable<Friend[]>;

    selectedFriend: Friend;

    onSelect(friend: Friend): void {
        this.selectedFriend = friend;
    }

    getFriends():void {
        this.friends = this.sharedFriends.getFriends();
        console.log(this.friends); // undefined
    }

    constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService, private sharedFriends: SharedFriendsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFriends();
        console.log(this.friends); // undefined
    }
}
```

Как по нормальному раздавать массив объектов `friends`? Отслеживать его состояние в файле не нужно. Нужно лишь один раз забрать его из файла, обработать и сделать так, чтобы он был доступен во всех компонентах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызов `this.http.get(this.apiHost)` - асинхронный. Соответственно и дальше с ним надо работать как с асинхронными операциями.

Сейчас получается так. Компонент запрашивает данные у `SharedFriendsService`, тот запрашивает данные у `FriendsService`, последний делает `AJAX` запрос.

Сервис **./friends.service.ts** (читает из JSON-файла массив объектов Friend):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Friend } from './friend';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable()
export class FriendsService {

    public apiHost: string = './assets/generated.json';

    constructor(private http: Http, private messageService: MessageService) {
       // здесь вызов getFriends не нужен
    }

    getFriends(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get(this.apiHost);

    }

}
```

Сервис **./shared-friends.service.ts** (Раздаёт массив объектов Friend и вносит некоторые изменения в объекты):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Friend } from './friend';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { FriendsService } from './friends.service';

@Injectable()
export class SharedFriendsService {

    constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService) { }

    getFriends():Observable<Friend[]> {
        return this.friendsService.getFriends().map(result => {
            let friends = result.json(); // здесь делаем необходимые манипуляции. Обратите внимание на map вместо subscribe.
            return friends;
        });
    }

}
```

Компонент **./friends-list/friends-list.component.ts** (используя сервисы выводит список друзей):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Friend} from '../friend';
import {FriendsService} from '../friends.service';
import {SharedFriendsService} from '../shared-friends.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-friends-list',
    templateUrl: './friends-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./friends-list.component.css']
})

export class FriendsListComponent implements OnInit {

    public friends: Observable<Friend[]>;

    selectedFriend: Friend;

    onSelect(friend: Friend): void {
        this.selectedFriend = friend;
    }

    getFriends(): void {
        this.sharedFriends.getFriends().subscribe(friends => {
            this.friends =  friends; // получаем список
        });
    }

    constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService, private sharedFriends: SharedFriendsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getFriends();
    }
}
```